# How to extract individual/child nodes from a KML file in VisualBasic?

Tags: vb.net, linq, kml, xmlreader

I need to be able to extract individual nodes from this file into variables for further manipulation. I'm writing to the console to see what information is being pulled, but I am struggling to pull the name or description.

I can successfully print the entire file. I've tried getting individual nodes using `placemark.<name>.Value` and `placemark.Element("name").Value`, the second of which throws a NullReferenceException. Any ideas on how to be able to pull out the name and description in this instance?

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq 'Visual Studio 2015 tells me this isn't needed
Imports System.Core 'Visual Studio 2015 tells me this isn't needed

Dim file As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath)

    Dim placemarks As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From test In file.Root.Elements()

            For Each placemark As XElement In placemarks
                Console.WriteLine(placemark) 'This works
                Console.WriteLine(placemark.<name>.Value) 'This prints an empty line
                Console.WriteLine(placemark.Element("description").Value) 'This throws a NullReferenceException
            Next
```

This is the structure

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Untitled layer</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Name 1</name>
            <description>Description 1</description>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='Test data one'>
                    <value>Test data 1</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>34725567547</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Name 2</name>
            <description>Description 2</description>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='Test data two'>
                    <value>Test data 2</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>056795763767</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you are trying to fetch the `name` & `description` present inside the `PlaceMark` node. But, since you are only fetching `Root.Elements()` your query will only fetch the complete XML starting from your root node.

You need to find the Descendants of `PlaceMark` node because you need to fetch the name & description inside it. Also, since the root node `kml` consists of namespace you need to specify that as well.

Here is the code:-

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
Dim placeMarks = From test In file.Root.Element(ns + "Document")
                                  .Descendants(ns + "Placemark") Select test

For Each pm In placeMarks
     Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", pm.Element(ns + "name").Value)
     Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", pm.Element(ns + "description").Value)
     Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

I am getting following output:-

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Your explanation helps me better understand how to achieve these results going forward. Thank you!!